# How to make my game stop after ten seconds in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, timer, libgdx

I'm almost done with my project to make a very simple game. The point of the game is to count how many times the user touches the screen and compare it to the number of times an object popped up on the screen to be touched. It's considered a win if number of touches = number of objects. All of this is to happen in 10 seconds, and I have no idea where to start on how to time the game? (It's supposed to be a veryyy very simple game just to learn how to use libgdx)

As of now, there's a start screen that the user touches to start and then the game starts where objects pop up to be touched. The problem is that it's basically an endless game right now... Here's how I make an object "randomly pop up":

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            touchCount++;
            Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3();
            touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            camera.unproject(touchPos);
            visual.x = MathUtils.random(10, 700);
            visual.y = MathUtils.random(100, 400);

        }
```

Do I have to put some built in timer function in this part of the code? And how to I go about tracking the touches to compare with the number of objects that popped up?

Thanks, any advice would be very appreciated!

Comment: [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Answer (score 1):

`System.currentTimeMillis()` gives you current time in milliseconds

For example you can do something like this

```
private long time;

    public void show(){
    //...
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    }
    public void draw(){
    //...
           if(System.currentTimeMillis()>time+10000){
                System.out.println("after 10 seconds");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use old fashioned java way either:

```
Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Pause your game or just close it...
                Gdx.app.exit();
            }
        }, 10000L);
```

Of course it's better to use synchronous timer approach, but for fast debuging or prototyping needs its sometimes more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Use the **delta** value inside your **render()** method.

```
render(float delta){
      //  ......

    if (yeni_oyun_mesaji_var_MI)// a boolean value to increment my time value only it is needed.
        oyun_uyari_zamani_tutucu += delta;

    if (oyun_uyari_zamani_tutucu > oyun_uyari_zaman_siniri) {// after some time (**oyun_uyari_zaman_siniri**) do what you need
        oyun_uyari_zamani_tutucu = 0f;
        oyun_durum_mesaji_str = "";
        yeni_oyun_mesaji_var_MI = false;
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Uyarı Kapatıldı!");
    }
}
```